# Taking user input for reading that many lines in a file

Tags: python

I am trying to take a user input to read that many lines into a text file. I have this so far, but get this error: 
in write_dogs line=f.next().strip() AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

This is my code as of now.

```
def write_dogs():
    total_cards = int(input("How many cards do you wish to play with? "))
    if total_cards %2 != 0:
        print("Please enter an even number")
        main_menu()
    elif total_cards > 30 or total_cards < 4:
        print("Please enter a number less that 30 and more than 4")
        main_menu()
    else:
        N = total_cards
        with open("dogs.txt") as f:
            with open("dogswrite.txt", "w") as f1:
                for i in range(N):
                    line=f.next().strip()
                    f1.write(line)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Working code is below

```
def write_dogs():
    total_cards = int(input("How many cards do you wish to play with? "))
    if total_cards %2 != 0:
        print("Please enter an even number")
        main_menu()
    elif total_cards > 30 or total_cards < 4:
        print("Please enter a number less that 30 and more than 4")
        main_menu()
    else:
        N = total_cards
        with open("dogs.txt") as f:#opens needed file
            with open("dogswrite.txt", "w") as f1:#my own file to later create a class
                for i in range(N):
                    line=next(f).strip()#lists the input number of results each on a new line
                    line = line + "\n"
                    f1.write(line)
```

Comment: try `next(f)` ?

Comment: Thanks this works, but i would like to have the copied results to have a comma between them. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Show the result you are getting in line and the expected output. The smallest possible example should be enough

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.next()` won't work here because `f` isn't a list, it's a file. You should instead be using `f.readline()`

Also, change your for loop to this:

```
for i in range(N):
    line=next(f).strip() + ', '
    f1.write(line)
```

EDIT: Didn't notice the indexed lines, also added the comma as per your comment

Comment: i may be missing something, but i get this when i do ur suggestion:      f1.write(line)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not builtin_function_or_method

Comment: When i do this, the whole list is copied not the user specified amount

Comment: @KithionPrathaban Sorry, I didn't notice that in my original read through of your question